# ScriptRunConfig and command

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to run a very simple test on an Azure Compute Cluster.

```
from azureml.core import Environment, Experiment, ScriptRunConfig, Workspace

ws = Workspace.from_config()
cmptgt = ws.compute_targets["my-d64sv3-c0"]

src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory=".", script="./hello_world.py",
            compute_target=cmptgt, environment=Environment("py310"))
run = Experiment(workspace=ws, name="my-hw1").submit(src)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

I get the following error

```
SnapshotException: SnapshotException:
    Message: ====================================================================

While attempting to take snapshot of /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/my-e64sv3-a/code/Users/fname.lname
Your total snapshot size exceeds the limit of 300.0 MB.
Please see http://aka.ms/aml-largefiles on how to work with large files.
```

which does not make sense because this is a simple hello-world.py example which does not need any data.  That directory is otherwise empty!  I am running this from a compute in the same workspace.

The alternative seems to be using `command` from `azure.ai.ml`.  To run that I need to create an `MLClient`.  Is there any way to create that MLClient object using the workspace object above.  Do I really need to provide subscription_id, resource_group_name again?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried the below python code to run a simple test in my Azure ML Compute and got the output like below:-***

**Code:**
The below is the [sample.py](http://sample.py) code:

```py
from  azureml.core  import  Workspace, Experiment, ScriptRunConfig
from  azureml.core.authentication  import  InteractiveLoginAuthentication
from  azureml.core.compute  import  AmlCompute
from  azureml.core.compute_target  import  ComputeTargetException
from  azureml.core.runconfig  import  RunConfiguration
from  azureml.core.conda_dependencies  import  CondaDependencies
from  azureml.core.environment  import  Environment
import  azureml.core
interactive_auth = InteractiveLoginAuthentication(tenant_id="tenant-id")
ws = Workspace.from_config(path="path/config.json")
src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory=".", script="path/hello_world.py ",
compute_target=ws.compute_targets["compute-name"], environment=Environment("py310"))
exp = Experiment(workspace=ws, name="workspace-name")
run = exp.submit(src)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

**Source code References:** Azure ML Python MS [Document 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.authentication.interactiveloginauthentication?view=azure-ml-py) & [Document 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.scriptrunconfig?view=azure-ml-py)

The below is the hello_world.py code:

```py
print("Hello, World!")
```

Below is config.json file:

```json
{
"subscription_id": "Subscription_id",
"resource_group": "Resource_group",
"workspace_name": "Workspace_name"
}
```

**Output:**
Successfully got the output like below:
[image]

It successfully completed the status in **MLworkspace** like below:

[image]

> **Reference**: Check this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-save-write-experiment-files?view=azureml-api-1&viewFallbackFrom=azureml-api-2#limits) for the error code you received.